Convert Full width numbers into Normal numbers in python
I have a data in an excel file(only 1 column) where there are several japanese characters followed by fullwidth numbers. I want to convert these numbers into normal numbers.
いつもありがとう８９０ございます
忙しい７ー１０ー１ところ

These are several rows like these.
What can I do so these rows could look like this:
いつもありがとう890ございます
忙しい7ー10ー1ところ

I tried doing this but I am not sure if this is how it should be done
like
s = unicodedata.normalize('NFKC', df.to_string())


What would the result be for that string?

Assuming such an example, in which col1 is the column to process:
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': ['いつもありがとう８９０ございます 忙しい７ー１０ー１ところ',
                            'いつもありがとう８９０ございます 忙しい７ー１０ー１ところ'],
                   'col2': [1, 2]
                  })

You can use apply:
import unicodedata
from functools import partial

df['col1'] = df['col1'].apply(partial(unicodedata.normalize, 'NFKC'))

Variant:
df['col1'] = df['col1'].apply(lambda s: unicodedata.normalize('NFKC', s))

Output:
                            col1  col2
0  いつもありがとう890ございます 忙しい7ー10ー1ところ     1
1  いつもありがとう890ございます 忙しい7ー10ー1ところ     2


Pandas' string methods has a normalise function: pandas.Series.str.normalize which takes the normalisation form as a parameter. This should be used in preference to str.normalize.
import pandas as pd
pd.options.display.unicode.east_asian_width: True
pd.options.display.unicode.ambiguous_as_wide: True
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'col1': [
        'いつもありがとう８９０ございます',
        '忙しい７ー１０ー１ところ'],
    'col2': ['1A', '2S']
})
df['col1'] = df['col1'].str.normalize('NFKC')

